# in jquery, how can i reference current form from button click

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form below; I have changed the submit button to just type "Button" so I would be able to run some JavaScript before submitting the form:

Here is my form:

```
<form action="/Cart" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="name" value="12" />
     <input type="button" class="addToCartButton" value="Add to Cart" />
 </form>
```

Here is my initial event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addToCartButton').click(function () {

       //need to reference current form here
       //need to reference the hidden input with name="Name" above
    });
});
```

I have a number of these forms on the same page so I need to relatively reference the form and some other inputs inside that form.  What is the best way to doing it?  I was thinking about putting some prefix that would be unique to each form and then using that in the selector but that seems very hacky ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addToCartButton').click(function () {

       //need to reference current form here
       $(this).closest('form');
       //need to reference the hidden input with name="Name" above
       $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="name"]');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery closest() will travel up the tree and return the first element that matches the selector:

```
$(this).closest("form");
```

Comment: htanks for the quick response.  what about referencing the other hidden fields inside the form, (now that you have the reference)

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can use `find('input[name="name"]')` although you might want to go with a more descriptive value than name, possibly formName?

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(this).siblings("input[name='name']"); // the field
 $(this).closest("form");  // the form
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.addToCartButton').click(function () {

       //need to reference current form here
       var the_form = $(this).closest("form");

       //need to reference the hidden input with name="Name" above
       var the_input = the_form.find('input[name="name"]');
  });
```